# Copying a file with php with correct context parameter

Tags: php, copy

I am trying to copy a txt file to another txt file with php like this:

```
<?php
echo copy("pos.txt","positions.txt");
?>
```

but I get an error :

> failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\Users\user\copy.php on line 2

I believe that if I pass the correct [context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) parameter, as I did with `fwrite` it will work as well but I have limited knowledge on php.

Comment: Do you have write permissions?

Comment: Yes please read below my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have write permission for that directory.

You use the directory from your script reside because you did not use full location:

`copy("pos.txt","positions.txt");`

you need to be shure that `this` directory have the `write permissions`

Comment: I have. That is not the problem. I faced the same problem with fwrite and providing a context parameter (an array or something) solved it